# How to change the default revision in Mercurial?

Tags: windows, mercurial, tortoisehg

When I `clone` the following project

http://code.google.com/p/signal-detector/source

it comes in the revision marked as `default`, that isn't the latest nor the `tip` revision.

I tried many merges to make the latest revision to become default, but I couldn't.

How to do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think I see what happened, you created a tag named `default` and you shouldn't.  In the absence of a tag `default` gets you the most tip-ward changeset with the branch name `default`.  However, since you have a tag named `default` that points to revision c257bbab2cf6c87b2c212aadbdd76f14c71e1ee2 you're getting that as the default update instead.

Delete the tag with:

```
hg tag --remove default
```

and I think you'll get the behavior you're expecting.

Comment: Thanks.  Only possible because Jader was good enough to post the repo link.  If this had been a private repo we'd all still be stuck.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
hg update
```

Comment: it only changed the current revision from one head to another, neither of those being the tip nor the most recent one. But my point is, I want to change the repository itself, so whenever someone clones it, it will already have the tip as the current revision

Comment: `tip` is always the most recent commit in the repository, regardless of where your `default` branch is, as such, if you have two branches, and commit in one, then in the other, and back and forth, `tip` will jump between the two branches for each commit.

Comment: @Jader Dias, `hg update`, without any arguments will always update the working copy to `tip`, so I don't understand the first part of your comment.

Comment: I think the tag `default` I created caused the unexpected behavior

Answer (score 1):

I assume the `default` tag you see isn't about the revision but the branch you're working on. That being said, check your current active heads by typing this:

```
hg heads
```

If you've got multiple heads, that means that you haven't merged everything back to the core line of the actual branch.
If it is the case, commit all your work (which will fall automatically into a new temporary branch). Then, pull the last revision from the source and then merge :

```
hg pull && hg merge
```

If there is a problem while on the pull/merging stage, try updating your current repository to a clean one by issuing this command:

```
hg update -C # Only if you've got problems with the previous command!
```

And then retry the merge operation.

I may have misunderstood your problem since I couldn't grasp all of your environment status, if it is the case, please excuse me.